# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have just cloned a repository containing a maven project based on Google App Engine. Next I have imported it into Eclipse Neon.

When eclipse/maven is done with importing the project I see that the below files have been modified and a new file has been created by eclipse:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
        modified:   project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        project/src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

When I build and run the application from eclipse I get this error:

```
WARNING: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
```

But from eclipse **com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet** is available:

[image]

Taking a closer look at: **project/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml** I see the below have been added by eclipse:

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>services</param-name>
   <param-value>com.project.[all the classes here.....]</param-value>
  </init-param>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

That appears to be related to the above error. But why do I get a **ClassNotFoundException** ?

As suggested below I have looked at the **deployment assembly**

[image]

Any yes indeed here I can add any jars on the filesystem. But why are the jars from **Google App Engine [Google App Engine 1.9.45]** not listed there? It has the **Maven Dependencies** but not **Google App Engine [Google App Engine 1.9.45]**. I would like to avoid adding jars this explicitly and instead have them pulled in by maven. Just seems strange to have both **Maven Dependencies** and  **Google App Engine [Google App Engine 1.9.45]** on the build path, should it not be enough with just having **Maven Dependencies**?

Comment: Have you already checked the "deployment assemblies" into the project's properties?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you be more specific what files/properties are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the **deployment assembly**:

In Eclipse, open the project's properties (right-clicking on it), and go to **deployment assembly**. Make sure that all of your libraries are included.

If not, click on "add.." and select whatever library is missing. (Typically at least the "java build path entries" should be included).

Comment: Ok now I see. Yes that is an option but I would like to specify my dependencies in my pom and not as physical files. See my updated post. Should it not be possible to only have Maven dependencies on the build path in eclipse remove the Google App Engine [Google App Engine 1.9.46] builder?

Comment: I agree with you: All dependencies should be centralized in the pom. But, by the image you posted, I see you have Google App Engine as a library apart of the Maven Dependencies. Have you included Google App Engine as a dependency in the pom? In that case, the only group required in the deploy assembly would be the Maven Dependencies.

Comment: I don't know where Google App Engine library comes from, I don't see anything in the pom that refers to it and no eclipse specific files are committed, strange

Comment: Surely GAE comes as an entry in your project's `.classpath` file. Anyway, you should find GAE-19.9.46 in a public M2 repository and set it as a dependency in the pom.